# Having troubling connecting SR-300 Camera in certain builds of Windows

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am using Intel® RealSense™ SR300 camera with the DiscoveryClient which comes as a sample for Project Gesture.

I have installed it on Surface Book and Surface laptop devices. The camera was constantly connecting and disconnecting when I attempted to use the Depth Sensor to recognize any gestures. It was, however working fine with other Laptops. Recently I have updated my version of Windows and now am having issues where the DiscoveryClient is unable to recognize the camera.

I have followed the troubleshooting issues on [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gestures/troubleshooting-realsense-camera). However, I have not found any solutions to the problem

I am seeing the following error in the DiscoveryClient:

```
[WorkflowManager] Workflow not loaded: Microsoft.Gestures.Runtime.Workflow.Manager.Exceptions.InvalidWorkflowException: None of the preconfigured workflows loaded successfully
    None of the preconfigured sensors loaded successfully
    Sensor plug-in Intel(R) RealSense(TM) Camera SR300 Depth is disconnected or failed to initialize.
    Sensor plug-in Intel(R) RealSense(TM) Camera SR300 Depth is disconnected or failed to initialize.
    Sensor plug-in Intel(R) RealSense(TM) Camera SR300 Depth is disconnected or failed to initialize.
    Sensor plug-in Intel(R) RealSense(TM) Camera SR300 Depth is disconnected or failed to initialize.
    None of the preconfigured sensors loaded successfully
    Sensor plug-in Intel(R) RealSense(TM) 410 Depth is disconnected or failed to initialize.
    Sensor plug-in Intel(R) RealSense(TM) 410 Depth is disconnected or failed to initialize.
    None of the preconfigured sensors loaded successfully
    Sensor plug-in WDF KinectSensor Interface 0 is disconnected or failed to initialize.
    Sensor plug-in WDF KinectSensor Interface 0 is disconnected or failed to initialize.
    None of the preconfigured sensors loaded successfully
    Sensor plug-in Intel(R) RealSense(TM) 3D Camera (Front F200) Depth is disconnected or failed to initialize.
    Sensor plug-in Intel(R) RealSense(TM) 3D Camera (Front F200) Depth is disconnected or failed to initialize. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Gestures.Runtime.Workflow.Manager.Exceptions.InvalidWorkflowException: None of the preconfigured sensors loaded successfully
    Sensor plug-in Intel(R) RealSense(TM) Camera SR300 Depth is disconnected or failed to initialize.
    Sensor plug-in Intel(R) RealSense(TM) Camera SR300 Depth is disconnected or failed to initialize.
    Sensor plug-in Intel(R) RealSense(TM) Camera SR300 Depth is disconnected or failed to initialize.
    Sensor plug-in Intel(R) RealSense(TM) Camera SR300 Depth is disconnected or failed to initialize. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Gestures.Runtime.Workflow.Manager.Exceptions.InvalidWorkflowException: Sensor plug-in Intel(R) RealSense(TM) Camera SR300 Depth is disconnected or failed to initialize.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Gestures.Runtime.Workflow.Manager.WorkflowLoader.SpecificWorkflowConfigurationLoad(String sensorFriendlyName, String sensorDataProcessorFriendlyName, String gestureDetectorFriendlyName, Object dynamicConfig, IAvailableWorkflowElements availableWorkflowElements, IDeviceManagerListener deviceManagerListener, TryingToSetupWorkflowEventHandler handler)
   at Microsoft.Gestures.Runtime.Workflow.Manager.WorkflowLoader.Load(IEnumerable`1 configurations, Object dynamicConfig, IAvailableWorkflowElements availableWorkflowElements, IDeviceManagerListener deviceManagerListener, TryingToSetupWorkflowEventHandler handler)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Gestures.Runtime.Workflow.Manager.WorkflowLoader.Load(IEnumerable`1 configurations, Object dynamicConfig, IAvailableWorkflowElements availableWorkflowElements, IDeviceManagerListener deviceManagerListener, TryingToSetupWorkflowEventHandler handler)
   at Microsoft.Gestures.Runtime.Workflow.Manager.WorkflowLoader.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<LoadAsync>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   at Microsoft.Gestures.Runtime.Workflow.Manager.WorkflowManager.<InitializeWorkflow>d__86.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be related to the specs of the USB cable. RealSense is rated at 2 Amps and most of the USB cables on the market are rated for 0.9 Amps. The moment we switched to a cable rated at 3 Amps, the issue went away. We have stress tested it with the new cables and we couldn't break the system, so far it's been robust. One more thing we did is to make sure to not have to use extension cables, so we have custom ordered 3 Amp USB C to USB A cables from Newnex for our needs.

Some good cables to look for:
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B076CV7MPB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076CV7MPB)
https://www.newnex.com/usb-type-c-cables-legacy.php (Look for power delivery 3 A)

Don't order general purpose cables like CableMatters or AmazonBasics, examples below:
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00DMFB5OK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DMFB5OK)
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01GGKYR2O](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01GGKYR2O)